# Checking if user is logged in using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to display a different navigation bar to my users based on if they're logged in or not. I have handled the registration and logging in stage, but having trouble checking if the users are logged in and displaying the correct navigation bar.

This is what I have in `AppController.php`:

```
public $components = array('Session', 'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'account'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home')
));

public $loggedIn = false;

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('home', 'register', 'login');
    if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
        $this->set('loggedIn', true);
    }
}
```

and then in my layout (not view):

```
<?php if ($loggedIn): ?>
    logged in
<?php else: ?>
    <li class="right"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, `$loggedIn` is always false. If do `$this->set('loggedIn', $this->loggedIn);` from within my individual controllers it works fine, but in an attempt to keep my code DRY I only want it in the controller that all my other controllers inherit from (`AppController`).

Is there an easy way to do this that i'm missing?

Comment: you should never pass variables to the view in beforeFilter - use beforeRender instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this has already been answered but I will post my findings anyway..

The way I solved this issue and made $loggedIn globally available was adding it to the AppController.php file in beforeFilter()

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
}
```

Comment: $this->Auth->loggedIn() has been removed in cakephp3. In cakephp3 you have to check $this->Auth->user('id').This returns NULL if user is not logged in already !

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

```
if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
```

Comment: No problem. Here's the link for this method as well: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::loggedIn

Answer (score 2):

For cakephp3

Controller wide:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    $this->set('login_status', $this->Auth->user('id'));
}
```

In Template you can the check session object

```
$user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code after login() action:

```
if($this->Auth->loggedIn()){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```